# Creating new list from two lists that contains only distinct items?

Tags: c#

I have two lists contains some values.I want to create new list and add all the values from two lists that all are distinct.

I am new to LINQ and not experienced in it yet. so i done that in this way but this is not what i wanted.

> The new list only contains that distinct values if the value is present in both list then that value will be only one time in the new list.

---

> I acheieved it by using Distinct Extension method but that is not what i wanted...i want that new list only contain the Distinct values.

Code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> firstList_names = new List<string>()
            {
                "Rehan",
                "Hamza",
                "Adil",
                "Arif",
                "Hamid",
                "Hadeed"
            };

            List<string> secondList_names = new List<string>()
            {
                "Mahboob",
                "Zeeshan",
                "Rizwan",
                "Hamid",
                "Rehan",
                "Hamza"
            };

            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            foreach (var nameOfFirstList in firstList_names)
                result.Add(nameOfFirstList);

            foreach (var namesOfSecondList in secondList_names)
                result.Add(namesOfSecondList);

            Console.Write(result.Distinct().Count());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need something like union?

Comment: yes. @A.Roussos

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen `Distinct()` is not working after `AddRange()` because that returns void.

Comment: What is the expected result? `Rehan Hamza Adil Arif Hamid Hadeed Mahboob Zeeshan Rizwan` or `Rehan Hamza Hamid` (or something else )?

Comment: this one )- `Rehan Hamza Adil Arif Hamid Hadeed Mahboob Zeeshan Rizwan`

Comment: @Rehan, you are getting varying answers that do different things because your lack of punctuation makes the question ambiguous.   Also, answerers are confused because the code in your own question already does exactly what you claim to want:   return the distinct values that result from combining the two lists.    You say that you don't want the Distinct() extension method, but why not, if your desired result is getting the distinct values?

Comment: Then you already have the solution. `var distinctResult = result.Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get only the items common to both lists, you can use the `System.Linq` extension method [`Enumerable.Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.7.2), which returns the *intersection* of two lists:

```
var intersection = firstList_names.Intersect(secondList_names);
```

---

There is some confusion on your question, however. If you want all the items from both lists (without any duplicates), then you can use the [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension method:

```
var union = firstList_names.Union(secondList_names);
```

---

If you want to do these the "old fashioned" way (without the extension methods), you could do something like the samples below.

For Intersection:

```
var intersection = new List<string>();

foreach(var item in firstList_names)
{
    if (secondList_names.Contains(item) && !intersection.Contains(item))
    {
        intersection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

For Union:

```
// Start with a list of the distinct firstList_names
var union = new List<string>();

foreach(var item in firstList_names)
{
    if (!union.Contains(item))
    {
        union.Add(item);
    }
}

// Add any items from the secondList_names that don't exist
foreach (var item in secondList_names)
{
    if (!union.Contains(item))
    {
        union.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: why i get downVoted ? look it my question carefully....i wrote everything right towards expectations...

Comment: I think it's mostly in the way the statement is phrased in the first yellow box in your question. Some people (myself included) thought you wanted only the items that were distinct to both lists (contained in both lists). One reason for downvoting is if the question is "unclear", so I suspect that is the reason. Don't take it personally, just try to improve the question (if you want to) and people may remove their down votes.

Comment: Using the example from your original post, you could have just added one more line: `result = result.Distinct();`

Answer (score 2):

Follow this example (taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
    int[] ints1 = { 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7 };
int[] ints2 = { 8, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0 };

IEnumerable<int> union = ints1.Union(ints2);

foreach (int num in union)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", num);
}

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 5 3 9 7 8 6 4 1 0
*/
```

Comment: That will also include items that are not in both lists!

Comment: @RehanShah I still don't get this: The new list **only contains that distinct values if the value is present in both list** then that value will be only one time in the new list. You should edit your question to make the requirements clear

Comment: @Peter, his requirement is very ambiguous because of missing punctuation.  It appears that by "...only contains that distinct values if the value is present in both lists..."  he really means  "...only contains the distinct values.  If the value is present in both lists..."      Also confusing because he wants distinct values but says he doesn't want to use the Distinct() extension method.

Comment: why i get downVoted ? look it my question carefully....i wrote everything right towards expectations...